# Vite - Multiple build outputs

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

I am using Nuxt 3 and there are many folders like `pages`, `layouts`, `middlewares` etc. which you can write in TS and it will build it JS into a folder named `dist`

Now I have a folder, let's call it `specialfolder`. This folder should get its own output folder let's say `special_output`

The structure looks like this:

```
-middlewares
-plugins
-specialfolder
-config
-layouts
-pages
```

After build it should look like this:

```
-middleware
-plugins
-specialfolder
-config
-layouts
-special_output
-dist
```

Everything gets compiled normally, only `specialfolder` gets compiled to its own folder, is something like this possible in Nuxt 3 (Vite)?

Comment: What is the content of this directory? What is the goal? This is not baked-in, so the fastest way would be to use some bash code in your CI or alike.